# How can I calculate the yaw of arUco marker?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, aruco

I'm trying to use arUco marker detection in openCV to calculate the angle of a marker in comparison to the camera's plain.

what's important to me is what angle the marker is rotated in accordance to the camera X-Y plain.

EDIT: changed the pictures, now from my code, including axis for markers and calculated angle.
**Picture A:**
[image: Picture A]
**Picture B:**
[image: Picture B]
**Picture C:**
[image: Picture C]
**Picture D:**
[image: Picture D]
picture A has the marker in front of the camera, and facing the camera.
picture B has the marker offset from the center of the camera, but still facing towards the camera's plain (so yaw angle should be 0 deg)
picture C has the marker rotated in 45 deg, and directly in front of the camera
picture D has the marker rotated in 45 deg angle, and offset from the center of the camera.

The end calculation has to result in a yaw angle of 0 degrees in pictures A and B, and 45 degrees in pictures C and D

for that purposes I tried the following code:

```
corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = aruco.detectMarkers(gray, aruco_dict)
rvec, tvec, x = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, 0.04, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs)
rmat, jacobian = cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)
world_angle = acos(rmat[0][0]) * 57.296
```

I appear to get the wrong angle. when I recreate the scenes in pictures A and B I get an angle of 20 degrees, and it stays wrong until around a 30 degrees of yaw. But on the other hand, for yaw angles > 45 degrees I get a correct answer.

Am I doing the calculation correctly? or is there some bug in the code? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add an image of your detected marker, possible with the axes drawn over the image? Are you keeping the marker at the vertical center of the image?

Comment: @Kani I added requested pictures. I'm trying to keep the marker at the vertical center of the image, but I can't commit to that. So solution that will include vertical shift will be better, but I'll appreciate one that uses markers on vertical center.

Comment: It seems like the Picture A is weird. If it is directly aiming at the camera, axis should not be drawn like that. Blue line is for too long to be pointing towards the camera.  It should be like [this](https://i.imgur.com/e8yyNJK.png). My suspicion is the camera calibration. I am running your calculation (you can see the yaw angle on the terminal in the image background.

Comment: that might be important, and worth taking a look at. What is the best way you know to calibrate the camera? in my case, I tried to use grid board to calibrate, but each picture I tried to use has returned different distance coeffs and camera matrix

Comment: Did you only use one image for the calibration? You might find [this](https://github.com/fdcl-gwu/aruco-markers) useful.